# How to get FB profile in FB auth using Android Studion Java with Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, facebook-authentication

// Why this method return different URL it doesn't get the actual profile picture?

```
String profileUrl = mUser.getPhotoUrl().toString() + "?height=500";
Glide.with(this).load(profileUrl).into(userProfile);
```

Comment: Have you only tried to use `Glide.with(this).load(mUser.getPhotoUrl().toString()).into(userProfile);`? Does it work that way?

Comment: Yes same output

Comment: If you try to log the value of `mUser.getPhotoUrl().toString()`, what exactly are you getting printed out?

Comment: https: //graph.facebook.com/365524062154675/picture

Comment: When i try to paste that url to the browser I get the same output in my program

Comment: So what's the problem then?

Comment: It doesn't get my actual profile picture in facebook

Comment: Are you sure that profile has a profile picture? I only see the default icon.

Comment: Yes I have a profile picture and I notice that the link from my facebook profile and the link return in glide is diffrent to each other.

Comment: Then it most likely means that the user authenticated in your app is different than the user you are checking in the browser, right?

Comment: I can get the name and my email correctly, but the only problem is the profile picture

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
Uri profileUrl = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getProfilePictureUri(500, 500);
Glide.with(this).load(profileUrl).into(userProfile);
```